# How to convert a field, which is an array of objects with K-V pairs to array of arrays with only values?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, geojson

I have a collection in MongoDB which has a field called **"geometry"** with latitude and longitude like this :

```
{ 
    "abc":"xyz",
    "geometry" : [
        {
            "lat" : 45.0, 
            "lng" : 25.0
        }, 
        {
            "lat" : 46.0, 
            "lng" : 26.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert the field **geometry** into something like this, to be compliant with the GeoJSON format:

```
{
            "abc":"xyz",
            "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        25.0,
                        45.0
                    ],
                    [
                        26.0,
                        46.0
                    ]
                ]                
            }
}
```

The operation essentially involves taking an array of objects with two K/V pairs and pick only the values and store them as array of arrays(with the order reversed- so value of "lng" comes first).

***My failed attempts:*** 
I tried using an aggregate and tried to project the following:

```
"geometry": {"type":"LineString", "coordinates":["$points.lng","$points.lat"] }
```

which gave me a result similar to:

```
"geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    25.0,
                    26.0
                ],
                [
                    45.0,
                    46.0
                ]
            ]                
        }
```

I've tried working with this and modifying data record by record, but the results are not consistent. And, I'm trying to avoid going through every record and changing the structure one by one. Is there a way to do this efficiently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would think that the following code should *theoretically* work:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "abc": 1, // include the "abc" field in the output
        "geometry": { // add a new geometry sub-document
            "type": "LineString", // with the hardcoded "type" field
            "coordinates": {
                $map: {
                    "input": "$geometry", // transform each item in the "geometry" array
                    "as": "this",
                    "in": [ "$$this.lng", "$$this.lat" ] // into an array of values only, ith "lng" first, "lat" second
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $out: "result" // creates a new collection called "result" with the transformed documents in it
})
```

**However**, the way MongoDB works at this stage as per [SERVER-37635](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37635) is that the above query results in a surprising output where the `coordinates` field contains the desired result several times. So the following query can be used to generate the desired output instead:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "abc": 1,
        "geometry2": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": {
                $map: {
                    "input": "$geometry",
                    "as": "this",
                    "in": [ "$$this.lng", "$$this.lat" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "abc": 1,
        "geometry": "$geometry2"
    }
}, {
    $out: "result"
})
```

In the comments section of the JIRA ticket mentioned above, Charlie Swanson mentions another workaround which uses `$let` to "trick" MongoDB into interpreting the query in the desired way. I re-post it here (note that it's missing the `$out` part):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "abc": 1,
      "geometry": {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            ret: {
              "type": "LineString",
              "coordinates": {
                $map: {
                  "input": "$geometry",
                  "as": "this",
                  "in": [
                    "$$this.lng",
                    "$$this.lat"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          in: "$$ret"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wdMj4ZQAHhc Not matching the desired output?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: It's a perfect match, I would say?! No, ok, it's not... Well spotted! But why??? This almost appears to be a MongoDB bug?!

Comment: Yes because It doesn't replace `geometry` field of the document with new `geometry` field used in `$project`. I was also wondered when answering the question. Happened same to me.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: LOL, thanks. Now, I can go to bed and you can have all the rest. ;)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for providing exactly what I needed.